# Java, Selenium. How to locate a hyperlink WebElement?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, build-automation

I'm trying to perform a click action on the "sign out" link on Gmail but my console keep saying that it's unable to locate the element. Below is my code.Thank you!

```
@FindBy(linkText="Sign out")
WebElement logoutLink;
```

This is the HTML:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ9SL.png)

And this is the WebElement:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI9r6.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XPath to locate that element:

```
"//a[contains(@href,'Logout')]"
```

Or this CSS Selector:

```
"a[href*='Logout']"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you observe closely the text ***Sign out*** is actually within a `<div>` which have an ancestor `<span>` which again have an ancestor `<a>`

So an effective [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) can be:

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath="//a//span//div[text()='Sign out']")
  WebElement logoutLink;
  ```